# _http_server.js:190 throw new RangeError(`Invalid status code: ${originalStatusCode}`); in node js?

Tags: node.js

i'm new to nodeJS technology, Actually i want to create a server and provide routing to another two files based on **request.url** but i runs , it was showing the above error, where it is showing invalid status code,

Here is my code

app.js

```
   var url = require('url')
var fs = require('fs')

function renderHTML(path , response){
   fs.readFile(path,null, function(error , data){
       if(error){

           response.write('file not found')
       } else{
           response.writeHead(data)
       }
       response.end()
   })   
}
module.exports = {
    handleRequest : function(request , response){
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : 'text/html'})
        var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
        switch(path) {
            case '/' :
               renderHTML('./index.html', response)
               break;
            case '.login' : 
               renderHTML('./login.html', response)
               break;
            default : 

               response.write('route not defined')
               response.end()
        }
    }
}
```

And my server.js looks like

```
    let http = require('http')
var app = require('./app.js')

http.createServer(app.handleRequest).listen(8001)
```

i have both index.html and login.html in my root directory..

what is the problem in above code.
please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For rendering your html file, you want to use `response.write()`, not `response.writeHead()`.

`response.writeHead()`, as his name suggests, is used to write the headers of your http response, like `response.writeHead('404')` if the file is not found. This is why you get the error message "Invalid status code", because the function expect a valid http code status (a number).

With `response.write()` you can send your file content, and `response.writeHead()` will be called internally to set the status (200).

Exemple:

```
function renderHTML(path, response) {
   fs.readFile(path, null, function(error, data) {
       if (error) {
           response.writeHead('404')
           response.end('file not found')
       } else {
           response.write(data)
       }
   })   
}
```